# GPO Application Error - Cannot Access GptTmpl.inf

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, windows-server-2022

In my organization's Windows AD environment, I cam across an error on several machines:

"Security policy cannot be propagated. Cannot access the template. Error code = -536870656.
\.net\sysvol<DOMAIN>.net\Policies{6AC1786C-016F-11D2-945F-00C04fB984F9}\Machine\Microsoft\Windows NT\SecEdit\GptTmpl.inf." (My local domain is .net; not .local).

NSLookup of FDQN returns in all DNS Server IP addresses; dir  returns files (which there are none) in the SYSVOL, DIR of the path, returns GptTmpl.inf as a result; so Browsing seems good.

What else should I try? Is the inf file an ASCII file; to be viewed in a simple text editor?

I looked through this link which both steps outlined here result in success; does not seem to be an issue with DNS.
[Windows cannot access the file gpt.ini for GPO error](https://serverfault.com/questions/314894/windows-cannot-access-the-file-gpt-ini-for-gpo-error)

Answer (score 1):

From the computer in error check if you can navigate to the folder with the user account of the user in problem;

.net\sysvol.net\Policies{6AC1786C-016F-11D2-945F-00C04fB984F9}\Machine\Microsoft\Windows NT\SecEdit\GptTmpl.inf

If you can navigate to the folder, it would possibly mean the Everyone security group from the GPO was removed and a special security group was added, but no access was gave to the computer account to read the GPO while the computer is in pre-login.

In the GPO Editor add in the delegate tab "Domain Computer" - Read, and try again.

Comment: This is from a FSMO Role Holder server; loggrf in as Administrator; browsing success. Also, with an end-user Windows 10 Pro Domain Joined workstation; browsing success.